# Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd cookie accumulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have a problem with Microsoft ReportViewer. 
With each new generated report added one new cookie like this:   `/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd%3FOpType%3DSessionKeepAlive%26ControlID%3Df6166329be5f4b00aa32320285ffaf55_SKA`
until the server starts to faill with an `Bad Request - Request too long` error because of too many cookies inside of request. 
I've tried manually to expire these cookies, with no success.
My initialization code for report viewer:

```
var credentials = new ReportViewerCredentials { NetworkCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials};            
           mainReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = credentials;
           mainReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
           mainReportViewer.ReportError += OnReportError;
           mainReportViewer.ShowRefreshButton = false;
           mainReportViewer.ShowWaitControlCancelLink = false;
           mainReportViewer.ShowBackButton = false;
           mainReportViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
           mainReportViewer.AsyncRendering = true;
           mainReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"]);
           ExtractReportParametersFromCookie(mainReportViewer);
           mainReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
          <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
          <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </buildProviders>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
         <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"  path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
```

Maybe someone has ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that `KeepSessionAlive="False"` solves the issue and could be used as workaround.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? In what section of Web.config or maybe rsreportserver.config this should be added?

Comment: It can be done in code, as in [reportViewer.KeepSessionAlive = false]